# How to deploy SpringBoot and Keycloak war on tomcat 9

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, keycloak

I want to  use  SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE, Keycloak 6.0.1, java 8  and  deploy the war  in  an  external  tomcat 9 that  also  has  other applications.

Keycloak  documentation mentions -
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/master/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/spring-boot-adapter.adoc

'If you plan to deploy your Spring Application as a WAR then you should not use the Spring Boot Adapter and use the dedicated adapter for the application server or servlet container you are using. Your Spring Boot should also contain a web.xml file.'

Keycloak  does not have  tomcat 9  adapter.

- is there any way  to deploy the war  on tomcat 9 ?
- in my app,  I don't  have web.xml.  Should  I create an  empty web.xml ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? How did you deploy it to tomcat?